# Come up with smooth and continuous function

Tags: analysis, continuity

I wonder if someone could help me with the following task or give some examples, advices at least. I need to come up with a real-valued, smooth function on $[-9,9]$ such that

- $|f(x)|\le 20$;
- $f(x) = kx + b$ on $[-1, 2]$;
- $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ on $[-5, -1]\cup [2, 6]$;
- $f(x) = \sqrt{R - (x - x_0)^2} + y_0$ on $[6, 9]$;
- $f(x) = a \sin(bx + y) + a \cos(bx + y)$ on  $[-9, -5]$ and has 4 zeroes in this interval

Comment: Must the coefficients $a$ and $b$ in the second, third and fourth request be the same?

Comment: @G.S., no, they all may be different